# Creating Textures loaded via file loader in pixi.js

Tags: typescript, webpack, pixi.js, webpack-file-loader

Hi I set up a project using Webpack, TypeScript and fileloader.

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        options: { /* Loader options go here */ }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },      
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": [
            "node_modules/*",
            "src/types/*"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

And my `index.ts`:

```
import * as  _ from 'lodash';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

const renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(256, 256,
    { antialias: false, transparent: false, resolution: 1 });

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

const stage = new PIXI.Container();

renderer.render(stage);
```

The above constellation renders the stage to `index.html` as expected.

Now I added a `bs.png` file to my `src/images/` folder, now my project structure looks like this:

[image]

As I understand it this `bs.png` gets loaded as the file `/dist/14145c56ece7799954586ba6f8464dbb.png`. Here my trouble begin. I try to load the image as follows. First I created a `custom.d.ts` which includes a module declaration for loading `.png` files:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Now in `index.ts` I load it via `import * as Image from './images/bs.png';`. The resulting `Image` is of the type function and the output of console.log(Image) is `14145c56ece7799954586ba6f8464dbb.png`. Unfortunately I am not able to load a Pixi texture like this:

```
const text = new PIXI.Texture(Image);
```

With this line I get:

```
src/index.ts(12,31): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof "*.png"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseTexture'.
  Property 'touched' is missing in type 'typeof "*.png"'.
```

Which I understand. I also cannot use:

```
const texture = PIXI.utils.TextureCache[Image];
```

Although Image does seem to return the filepath. I tried to load the image using the filepath of the `png` created by webpack, still the texture remains `undefined`.

I am really unsure what the real problem here is. Do I need to run a server (such as express) or am I just missing something? Btw this is the output of the `npm run build` command using `awesome-typescript-loader`:

```
> webpack

Hash: 45f5667bd75205a328bf
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 3297ms
                               Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
14145c56ece7799954586ba6f8464dbb.png  4.07 kB          [emitted]
                           bundle.js  4.83 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [16] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
  [37] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
  [88] ./src/index.ts 851 bytes {0} [built]
 [192] ./src/images/bs.png 82 bytes {0} [built]
    + 189 hidden modules
```

Comment: Well at least I would recommend to make sure the Image has been loaded before using it. Since in the example you try to retrieve an image from TextureCache, but I do not see where you actually add it to the cache. So you can use at least the loader: http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.loaders.Loader.html for that. So something like:
loader.add('bunny', 'data/bunny.png');
loader.load((loader, resources) => { Create the sprite from the image in cache })
...
Also when creating textures, you should probably use: let texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage, instead of constructor

Answer (score 1):

You have path of image and you need to load it before using it.

```
 PIXI.loader.add([
        Image,
        "and_others_if_any.png",
       ])
        .load(() => {
           var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.fromImage(Image));

       });
```

And this operation will do an ajax request so you need to serve these files from a server. If you are on linux you can serve by running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` command from working directory.